# Dynamically creating a number of class objects

Tags: node.js, class

I have this class object, I need to create a new Person() class object for each user that exists.
Say I have users (user1, user2, user3) I need to create 3 Person() Objects. How can I do this dynamically?

```js
function Person() {
  this.user = 'user_1';
}
Person.prototype.setName = function(user) {
  this.user = user;
};
Usernames = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
var Example = new Person();
Example.setName(Username[0]);

var Example2 = new Person();
Example.setName(Username[1]);

var Example3 = new Person();
Example3.setName(Username[2]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An even simpler approach to Sudhakar RS' answer:

```
Usernames = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];
let persons = Usernames.map(name => {
    let person = new Person();
    person.setName(name);
    return person;
});
```

This approach allows further abstraction and a more functional approach while maintaining  immutability/stability. For instance:

```js
let Usernames = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];
let persons = Usernames.map(createPersonWithName);

function createPersonWithName(name) {
  let person = new Person();
  person.setName(name)
  return person;
}
```

Being able to isolate things in this way can be incredibly valuable in other ways, whether you are doing arrays of objects or closely related arrays. Honestly, the array of objects is the best and easiest, though.

```
Users = [{
  name: 'user1',
  data: 'value1'
}, {
  name: 'user2',
  data: 'value2'
}, {
  name: 'user3',
  data: 'value3'
}];

let persons = Users.map(createPerson);

function createPerson(user) {
  let person = new Person();
  person.setName(user.name);
  person.setData(user.data);
  return person;
}
```

Using multiple arrays though often requires reaching out of scope or fancy other tricks that are considered by many to be smelly. A simple way to do this:

```
let Usernames = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];
let Userdata = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
let persons = Usernames.map(createPersonWithName);

function createPersonWithName(name, index) {
  let person = new Person();
  person.setName(name)
  person.setData(Userdata[index]);
  return person;
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Do you mean another array inside Usernames? Or do you mean another equally sized array of values referenced by the createPerson function? Or something else?

Comment: another equally sized array of values. I would just be setting another variable from another array which is of equal size to the usernames under the same person object the username is assigned to.

Comment: There are two options. Since it is closely tied to this answer, I can certainly consider it an expansion of the original answer.

Comment: If you would be so kind.

Comment: There are two more examples there for you. Honestly, the first is better, ***whenever possible***

Comment: For reference, you can look up `Array.prototype.map` which can apply to any array. It takes a function as its argument with the signature fn(value, key/index, array). The 1st argument is almost always the most important, so many examples of code only use the 1st argument, like my original `createPersonWithName`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
var Example=[];

for(let i=0;i<Usernames.length;i++){
    Example[i] = new Person();
    Example[i].setName(Username[i]);
}
```